# Foreach in a modal

Tags: php, html, sql, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to foreach in this modal, I would like to make it if you want to delete this car you see a list of all the people that rented this car. So I need to foreach all the output but it will give me this error:

> **Warning**:  Illegal string offset 'Voorletters' in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Rent-a-Car\pages\auto.php** on line **177**
> 1

This is my code I am trying:
The `$results['Kenteken'];` is the platenumber of the car and is set

```
<form method="post">
<div class="modal fade" id="ver<?php echo $results['Kenteken']?>" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Weet u zeker dat u de volgende auto wilt verwijderen?</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="icon-box">
    </div>
    <p> De volgende klanten huren deze</p>
    <?php 

        $klanttest = $results['Kenteken'];
        $sqltest = "SELECT * FROM factuur 
                LEFT JOIN factuurregel ON factuur.Factuurnummer = factuurregel.Factuurnummer
                LEFT JOIN gebruiker ON factuur.Klantcode = gebruiker.Klantcode
                LEFT JOIN auto ON factuur.Kenteken = auto.Kenteken
                WHERE factuur.Kenteken = :klant";


        $stmt = $db->prepare($sqltest);
        $stmt->execute([':klant' => $klanttest]);
        $data = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($data as $huurders) {
            echo $huurders;
        ?>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Kenteken" value="<?php echo $huurders['Voorletters']; ?>">
        <?php } ?>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="Kenteken" value="<?php echo $results['Kenteken']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Delete" style="float:left; background-color:orange; color:white;">Verwijder</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$huurders` is a string value, not an array. So trying to access `$huurders['Voorletters']` doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Use `$huurders` instead `$huurders['Voorletters'];`

Comment: `var_dump($huurders)` it is a string right? You probably want to be looping that fetch. `while($huurders = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){` and remove the `foreach`

Comment: Looks like you are expecting `$data` to hold all the result records of your query? It doesn’t, because you only fetched a single one. You need a method like `fetchAll` or something, if you want to fetch all records in one go.

Comment: I see what you guys are saying! And it helps! but still a question: What if I only want to foreach the ['Voorletters'] How do I get that?

Comment: `SELECT Voorletters FROM` then do the `while .. fetch` or the `fetchall`. Don't use `*` if you only want 1 column.